# Polling Rate of Mouse Creating Frequency Noise?

Tags: window-manager, wayland, x

I'll begin with an overview of my system:

- Generic Corsair case
- Asus Z170 AR Motherboard
- 8gb x 2 (16gb) Ballistix RAM
- i5 6600k
- Radeon RTX 480 4gb
- EVGA 650W Gold
- Logitech G403 mouse
- 144hz monitor
- Headset with external sound card

I have been using various flavors of Linux on this build for quite some time in a dual boot setup, and have finally settled on Fedora.  Originally I started with the full Workstation 29 install (with no issue), but decided to do a minimal install for more control over the packages.  I started by giving Wayland and Sway a try, only to first encounter my issue:

> This "grinding" or "scratching" noise coming from somewhere near my motherboard/PSU only when I move the mouse, scroll, or drag a window.

I initially chalked it up to bad drivers and Wayland, so I went with a full fresh install (probably over-kill) and installed X with i3.  Everything seemed fine, but after about 30 minutes **the noise came back**.

Now, I've seen a LOT of posts online talking about grounding the case and motherboard power savings modes, but none of those have worked - **with one exception**.  When I used a low quality 125hz mouse the noise goes away.  Aha!  I found it!  Not quite... I followed the Arch wiki to pass mouse polling rate parameters into my kernel on boot (using this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters)) and confirmed that my 1000hz gaming mouse was now polling at 125hz.  The noise was still there.

> Why do I encounter a grinding, frequency noise when using a window manager, but not a regular desktop environment?

I have never experienced this with KDE, XFCE, or GNOME, but as soon as I switch to Sway or i3 it comes back.  The polling rate of the mouse does not appear to impact it.  I have tried using `alsamixer` to disable all sound cards except the external one for my headset to no avail.  This issue is not related to distribution or even OS (not reproducible on Windows).

**EDIT:**

After installing a compositor (compton), the noise is *much* quieter.  I'm wondering if maybe this was just the processor working overtime instead of pushing the tasks off to the GPU?  The noise *is* still noticeable however.  I will continue to tweak.